# I'm working on a code simulator in C++ and I want some suggestions in choosing a suitable data structure to be able to store and manipulate this data

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

```
0 TRUE 3 FALSE 2 FALSE
0 FALSE 1 0x3 3 0x2
```

This is the content of file and syntax is the following:

```
rowNumber signal@rowNumber colNumber1 signal@colNumber1 colNumber2 signal@colNumber2 ..... colNumberN signal@colNumberN
```

note: only the first 2 terms are row values, the subsequent terms of a line are column details.

This has to be mapped to a crossbar array structure as shown below:

```
    0   1   2   3
    |   |   |   |  
0- [x] [y] [ ] [ ]
1- [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
2- [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
3- [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]

The example of operations I need to perform in the data structure is given below.

The value of x -> minimum(signal@row0, signal@column0, past value of x)
The value of y -> minimum(signal@row0, signal@column1, past value of y)
```

Dynamic allocation of memory is expected as the size of crossbar array is unknown in the beginning.

Given these requirements, what would be the most suitable data structure in C++ to represent and manipulate this crossbar array efficiently?

I have considered option such as std::vector, std::map but is not clear which one would be efficient to hold values and manipulate the values properly.

Comment: When you get to a point where you're holding multiple forms of data, and a data structure isn't immediately apparent, consider composing your data into a `struct` or `class`. From there, the purpose of a `std::map` is to retrieve these objects via some index/lookup, or a `std::vector` can hold multiple of those objects. It seems like some form of 2d array (which is translatable to a 1d array) would be appropriate, but I'm not certain how you got from your initial input to the desired output/state. More information regarding the `signal@some#` bit would help.